# How to save multiple sets of data from ul elements using one button in flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have some code that I am refactoring from using excel sheets to a mysql database within mysql.

Currently the app is set up like so;

There is a jinja template that loops through data obtained from a mysql table. There are multiple `ul` elements being displayed. Within the `ul` elements there is a `checkbox` and some other data.

What I want to achieve is to be able to go through 'checking' the `checkbox` if the data is relevant and then click a button to save changes.

However at the moment I only submit the data from the first row of the mysql table i.e. the first `ul` element.

I did try another way by attaching a button to each `ul` element and this worked the way I wanted it to, by posting the relevant data and was able to update the table accordingly, however my friend who I am refactoring the code for, wants to keep the universal 'save' button.

Is it possible to get all the results with one 'save' button?

Here is my html jinja code;

```
{% extends "home.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        <form action="/" method="post">
            {% for x in data %}
                <ul>
                   <li>{{ x.company }}</li>
                   <li>{{ x.name }}</li>
                   <li>{{ x.phone }}</li>
                   <li><input type="checkbox" name="relevant" value="Is relevant?" />
                </ul>
                <input type="hidden" name="company" value="{{ x.company }}" />                   
                <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ x.name }}" />                  
                <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="{{ x.phone }} }}" />

            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Changes" />
        </form>

    {% endblock %}
```

Here is my `app.py` code (just the post part);

```
if request.method == 'POST':

        if 'save' in request.form:

            user = request.form['user']
            phone = request.form['phone']
            company = request.form['company']

            if 'relevant' in request.form:
                #mysql statement to go here to update table 
                #if check box ticked
```

Comment: You should use different name for each checkbox.

Comment: @stamaimer Do you mean generate a random one? Or maybe use the `{{ x.name }}` variable appended to the `relevant` name?

Comment: You can use a identify name related to current data record. `{{ x.name }}` is okay.

Comment: @stamaimer Unfortunately this produces the same result. Only the first record set of data gets posted

Comment: My fault. http://w3school.com.cn/tiy/t.asp?f=html_input_checkbox